# How to configure Textmate to run JRuby?

Tags: jruby, textmate

Trying to work on JRuby with TextMate.

Answer (score 1):

While setting TM_RUBY tells TextMate to run JRuby where Ruby is run, it is not going to be a very pleasant experience.

TextMate relies so much of its functionality on Ruby. For example, ⌘-R in a Ruby source won't work. Other bundles may fail if they run Ruby code (and there are many).

If you just want to run the current file with JRuby and return output somewhere (not the pretty window that TextMate gives), you can use $TM_FILENAME and so on to build your own command.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/drnic/ruby-tmbundle

set the TM_RUBY to /usr/local/bin/jruby or where every you have jruby installed